# Relative submodule URL to another GitLab group

Tags: git, gitlab

Using [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/), I have a project `myproject` setup under a group `myteam`, which lives at this URL:

```
git@mycompany.com:myteam/myproject.git
```

The project has a couple submodules, which in the `.gitmodules` file looks like:

```
[submodule "libs/mylib"]
    path = libs/mylib
    url = git@mycompany.com:myteam/mylib.git
[submodule "libs/theirlib"]
    path = libs/theirlib
    url = git@mycompany.com:otherteam/theirlib.git
```

I would like to replace these absolute URLs with relative URLs.  For example:

```
[submodule "libs/mylib"]
    path = libs/mylib
    url = ../mylib.git
[submodule "libs/theirlib"]
    path = libs/theirlib
    url = ../theirlib.git           # ???
```

While this works for `mylib` (because it's in the same `myteam` group as `myproject`), it obviously doesn't work for `theirlib`, as it is in the `otherteam` group.

Is there a way to reference `theirlib` via relative URLs?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use

```
url = ../../otherteam/theirlib.git
```